# Error changing column names of data frames in a list-R

Tags: r

I have such a list(list1) each element is a data frame which consist one column.

All columsn names are same "x". I want to change column names as "x1", "x2",....,"xn".

I use below code:

```
lapply(list1, function(x) setNames(x, "x",paste("x",1:seq_along(list1))))
```

However, this code does not work. Why does not this code work? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

@ David Arenburg, I edited code as below(10 is the elment number in list1):

```
lapply(list1, function(z) setNames(z,paste0("x",1:10)))
```

This code does not give any error but it also does not change the column names.The column names ars still "x".

I edited the as below, however, it doesn't still work.

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
  list2[[i]]<-setNames(data.frame(list1[[i]])[,1], paste0("x",1:10)[i])
}
```

I removed `seq_along`  for now. I will work on it after gettin the desired result.

Each element of list1 is a data frame and each data frame has only one column.

Comment: This is not reproducible, but `1:seq_along(list1)` won't work properly. Try `1:seq_along(mtcars)`. This should be just `seq_along(mtcars)`. But in your case it's not clear how do you use `x` here, as you still passing `list1` into `seq_along`. This doesn't make any sense to me. Also, your `setNames` usage is unclear. It should have 2 inputs- not 3. And probably this should be `paste0`- not `paste` as you probably want your names to be synthetically valid.

Comment: Are you assigning the result to an object?

Comment: `setNames` doesn't modify in place. You need to assign it somewhere. And as I already mentioned, [this isn't reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And what happened to `seq_along`? And what do you mean by "*consist one column*"? How many columns are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the name of each column in multiple data frames that make a list, you should do the following:

```
# Artificial list with each data frame containing columns with values from 1 to 3

list1 = list(data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 1:3),
         data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 1:3),
         data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(x = 1:3),
         data.frame(x = 1:3))

# Assigning column names of individual data frames

for(i in 1:length(list1)){
  colnames(list1[[i]]) = paste("x",i, sep = "")
}
```

I created a list with multiple data frames each one of them containing same column x. Because you want to change the names of columns in data frames, assigning multiple values in `setNames()` to each individual data frame will be of no help. Therefore, you have to paste x with single values (from 1 to length of your list) to the column names of individual data frames.